# join 2 queries in one as subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have a table like this show referrs :

```
    id - name - referred_id - referred_name
    1  - mark -   100  -      nick
    2  - david-   100  -      nick 
    3  - mat -    100  -      nick
    4  - patrik-  101  -      robert
```

i want to get result like this : just show referred_id => 3 records

```
    refered_id - refered_name - Row(count)
    100        - nick         - 3
```

my two queries:

```
    "select count(*) as row(count) from Referral_info where row(count) > 3"
```

and

```
    "select referred_id,referred_name from Referral_info"
```

How can i join this queries into only one ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for group by?

```
select referred_id,referred_name , count(*) as RowsCount from Referral_info
    group by referred_id,referred_name
    having count(*) > 3
```